# Ignore ImportError when exec source code

Tags: python

I have an application that reads test scripts in python and sends them across the network for execution on a remote python instance.  As the controlling program does not need to run these scripts I do not want to have all the modules the test scripts use installed on the controller's python environment.  However the controller does need information from the test script to tell it how to run the test.
Currently what I do to read and import test script data is something like

```
with open( 'test.py', 'r' ) as f:
    source = f.read()

m = types.ModuleType( "imported-temp", "Test module" )
co = compile( source, 'test.py', 'exec' )

exec co in m.__dict__
```

which yields a new module that contains the test.  Unfortunately exec will raise ImportErrors if the test tries to import something the controller does not have.  And worse, the module will not be fully imported.

If I can guarantee that the controller will not use the missing modules, is there someway I can ignore these exceptions?  Or some other way to find out the names and classes defined in the test?

Examples test:

```
from controller import testUnit
import somethingThatTheControllerDoesNotHave

_testAttr = ['fast','foo','function']

class PartOne( testUnit ):
    def run( self ):
        pass
```

What the controller needs to know is the data in _testAttr and the name of all class definitions inheriting from testUnit.

Comment: The `try:` statement allows you to ignore the `ImportError`.  Isn't that what you're looking for?

Comment: Can I have the address of this remote python instance??  I feel like mischief!

Comment: @Andrew Its a private net :P Also the remote python instances are created and controlled by the controller, they will only respond to python data from the one trusted source. haha

Comment: one word, disgruntled co-worker.

Comment: Even if, he would only be able to destroy his own data.  Python instances are created via an ssh connection initiated using his login creds.  Im not going to say it is completely secure, but we are satisfied with it :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Write an import hook that catches the exception and returns a dummy module if the module doesn't exist.

```
import __builtin__
from types import ModuleType

class DummyModule(ModuleType):
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        return None
    __all__ = []   # support wildcard imports

def tryimport(name, globals={}, locals={}, fromlist=[], level=-1):
    try:
        return realimport(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
    except ImportError:
        return DummyModule(name)

realimport, __builtin__.__import__ = __builtin__.__import__, tryimport

import sys   # works as usual
import foo   # no error

from bar import baz     # also no error
from quux import *      # ditto
```

You could also write it to *always* return a dummy module, or to return a dummy module if the specified module hasn't already been loaded (hint: if it's in `sys.modules`, it has already been loaded).

Comment: Thats interesting, I thought about writing an enhanced importer but not about returning a dummy module..  this could work :) However i think the accepted way to add a custom importer is using imputil http://docs.python.org/library/imputil.html  Your way would work too though :P

Comment: On second thought, I think that since you're not actually executing the code, you could just return *anything* rather than going to the trouble of constructing a dummy module. `None` would probably work fine...

Comment: Looks like you have to be careful though, something like import os.path as op will fail because import os will return None.  It also does not seem to work to when you do 'from something import foo'  Going to have to get a little more complicated for a good solution

Comment: Hm. Guess you do need a dummy module with a `__getattr__` that will return something. Let me have a whack at that...

Comment: Work great, only thing I can find now is if you try to import from an existing module a non-existent module.  Ie.  from os import bar.  Not sure what to make of it, except that somehow the import tries to use the read builtin rather then your custom one.

Comment: Yes, if you already imported `os` then any reference to that module is going to refer to the existing one. You could change the importer to always return a dummy module, as long as you've imported everything you need to by then.

Comment: ahh right, that makes sense.  Thanks, there is just one small thing and I think this is perfect.  Instead of returning None in getattr I changed it to return a new DummyModule.  This allows me to do: from bar import baz; class Test( baz.Test )

Comment: In python 3, the same idea works substituting __builtin__ for builtins as a module. Useful for making your own plugin system with delayed dependency meeting.

Answer (score 3):

I think, based on what you're saying, that you can just say:

```
try:
    exec co in m.__dict__
except ImportError: pass
```

Does that help?

Comment: Importing of the module will stop when ImportError is raised.  So m ends up only containing the objects defined before the ImportError was raised

Answer (score 3):

You could use python ast module, and parse the script to an AST tree and then scan through the tree looking for elements of interest. That way you don't have to execute the script at all.

Comment: hmm, compile() will return an AST object, but I did not think I would get any useful information from it.  Maybe I should look deeper into that.

Comment: @Charles, you can look at any piece of the python code. So you can check for assignments to _testAttr, and class definitions. I'm not sure if its better then the dummy module trick. It does feel slightly less like a hack.